# Share the database between vmware guest and host

Tags: mysql, windows, mac-os-x, vmware

I wanna Access the MySQL Database **founded in Windows 10 from VMware Workstation MAC OS X guest and give the guest ( *MAC in VMware* ) only permissions to just one database** from the host (Windows 10),

I mean I want the Mac guest can access to one database from the host (NOT For ALL Databases).

I am connected in the guest by bridge network adapter. 
I know I must do a change in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf but don't know what. ( I am using XAMPP 7.1.6, it's doesn't have bind_address ).

I want the database always up in my machine ( Windows 10 ) and when I run the VMware mac guest ( MAC ) so the guest can access to this database.

( I mean I want the database to be accessed in the host ( although when VMware is off ) .

I have already made a database in PhpMyAdmin in the host ( Windows 10 ), **How can I access to just this database from the MAC guest in the VMware**.

I wanna mention I don't want to give permissions to this database to another computers in my Network, or another computers that have my IP Address.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to comment out the single line in the `my.cnf:

```
 bind_address = 127.0.0.1
```

By default `mysql` server listen only on the `localhost` for security reason. When that line is commented, `mysql` server become listening on the all available interfaces because default value is `bind_address = *`. Now you can connect to the `mysql` from the host OS by IP-address of the VM.

To restrict guest access to the single database/schema you have to perform the next query:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* 
   TO 'guestuser'@'1.2.3.4' 
   IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
```

where `1.2.3.4` is an IP-address of your host OS.

If you have dynamically assigned IPs on your LAN then you have to allow connections from the whole subnet your IPs are belongs to:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* 
   TO 'guestuser'@'192.168.%' 
   IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
```

where `192.168.%` means `192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255`

Comment: If you have used bridged interface for VM then it has an IP assigned by DHCP server on the LAN the same way your host OS has. Run `cmd` command in the windows then run `ipconfig` command in it. `guestuser` is just a placeholder for the login name used for connections to the `mysql` server. Replace it to the arbitrary name you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I don't have a bind_address line in the my.cnf, in my [mysqld] I have user, port, socket.. and more. Another thing what is the guestuser ? what is this user name mean ? And what about the ip, my lan ip isn't static what can I do for that ?,how I can make the ip for the VMware static ?
FYI I have XAMPP 7.1.6 Thanks

Comment: Thank you al lot man. Can you please edit your solution and be more specific and tell me in steps what to do. 
step 1 - is to make the network adapter in the VMware bridged.
step 2 - run ifconfig in the OS X ( guest ) 
step 3 - run this command in PHPMYADMIN in WINDOWS 10 ( The Host ) and choose the database name I want to share and choose the LAN IP for the guest OS X and then what to do ?